# Referencing javax.speech in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java, but I need to get a project written by someone else working in Eclipse Indigo.  It uses speech recognition, so it's missing the javax.speech library and I can't figure out how to install it so I can reference it in the build path.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check Oracle's page about the [Java Speech API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html)?  Re-reading your question - are you asking how to install a known library in Eclipse or where to get the library in the first place?

Comment: uh, both I think.  I'm just trying to get project to compile.  I know it works if you have the project set up correctly, but i have hundreds of errors related to missing library files all related to javax.speech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Speech API's are not included with the SDK. You need to download the JAR files for a valid implementation and include them on your class path. There is a (presumably current) [list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html#implementation) of providers on the [Oracle Java Speech API Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html) page:

- [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/)
- [IBMs "Speech for Java"](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/speech)
- [The Cloud Garden](http://www.cloudgarden.com/)
- [Lernout & Hauspie's TTS for Java Speech API](http://www.lhs.com/)
- [Conversa Web 3.0](http://www.conversa.com/)
- [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/)
- [Elan Speech Cube](http://www.elantts.com/products/fp_speechcube.html)

There are likely other providers out there, you will have to do some research. Also, note that some of the implementations listed are commercial.

Comment: How do I figure out which implementation was used in the project I'm using?

Comment: Was the original project code written in Eclipse? It should have come to you bundled with the libraries it depends on. If not then you may need to contact the original project developer.

Comment: Yea it was written in eclipse, but it doesn't have the library in it.  The original developer wants $250 just to answer this question.  Looks like I'll have to dig out an old system that has the project set up on it already to find it.

Comment: ah, figured it out.  it was cloud garden.  thanks for the help

Comment: Was just about to recommend that you use FreeTTS, as long as their were no implementation specific dependencies in the code. But you got it figured out ... cheers.